# jQuery: Add / Remove style while scrolling past div's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this page (https://www.datacoral.com/architecture/) that has a left sidebar with five bullet points. What I want to happen is as the user scrolls past these five div's on the right hand column, the text in one of these bullet points adds a class called 'bolder' and the text become a font-weight of 700 to let the user know what point they are in on the page. As the pass by that same div, the class disappears and ends up in the next bullet point since you're now passing by another div.

I've got it partially working but it's not hitting the right point of the div at all. Seems to add the class as you are passing the bottom of the div instead of the top.

This is the code I'm currently working with. Anyone know what I might be doing wrong so this can function properly?

Note: Should mention I'm basically duplicating this code five times and just swapping out the numbers.

```
jQuery(function(){
        jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop(); // how many pixels you've scrolled
        var os = jQuery('#guide_body-0').offset().top; // pixels to the top of div1
        var ht = jQuery('#guide_body-0').height(); // height of guide_body-0 in pixels
            if(scroll > os + ht){
                jQuery('.scroll-nav-0').addClass('bolder');
             }
         });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think firing a function on scroll like that gets a little bit crazy. I always delay the function until the scrolling has stopped.

As far as the catch point, i think your code is applying the classes when the element has moved out of view. i would use the bottom of the browser screen as a reference point.

Think about it like this:

1. `$(window).scrollTop()` returns 0 at the top of the page.
2. `$('#guide_body-0').offset().top` returns 1000px.
3. So `$(window).scrollTop()` is equal to `$('#guide_body-0').offset().top` when that element is at the top of the screen.
4. Add `$('#guide_body-0').height()` to the equation and that puts the scroll position (the top of the screen) at the bottom of the element.

What you need to do is check if the offset.top property of the element is in a scroll position which puts it above the bottom of the screen.

- UPDATE

The code here is for a custom solution. But if you are looking for a way to just add simple animations to elements as they scroll into view, check out wow.js and animate.css

https://wowjs.uk/
https://animate.style/

```js
// Init variable for timer
let timer;
// Get target element
const el = $("#4");
// Get viewport height
const screen = window.innerHeight;

// Fire callback on window scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {
  // Clear timeout just in case
  clearTimeout(timer);
  // Check if the element already has the class
  if (!el.hasClass("active")) {
    // Set a delay timer then run the function
    timer = setTimeout(check_el_pos, 300);
  }
});

function check_el_pos() {
  // Clear the timer
  clearTimeout(timer);
  // Get current scroll position
  let scroll_pos = $(window).scrollTop();
  // This is the math here. Add scroll position to screen height and you get the bottom of the screen. When that value equals the top offset of the element, we are there. 
  if (scroll_pos + screen > el.offset().top) {
    console.log(scroll_pos + screen);
    console.log(el.offset().top);
    // Add the classes to the element. Boom, we're done.
    el.removeClass("active").addClass("active");
  }
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.example-grid {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 40px;
}

.example-grid>li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 65vh;
  background: slategray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 1em;
  transition: background-color 1s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.example-grid>li:nth-child(even) {
  background: coral;
}

.example-grid>li.active {
  background: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="example-grid">
  <li id="1">1</li>
  <li id="2">2</li>
  <li id="3">3</li>
  <li id="4">4</li>
  <li id="5">5</li>
  <li id="6">6</li>
  <li id="7">7</li>
</ul>
```